# NPM Install on Network Shared Folder UNC Path Error

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install

I'm creating a project in a network shared folder of an intranet server. I'm a beginner and I do not exactly know what should I do.

This is what I'm fetching in my package.json

```
{
    "name": "Test Project",
    "version": "0.0.1",
    "description": "My Test Project",
    "dependencies": {
        "animate.css": "3.5.2",
        "font-awesome": "4.7.0",
        "vue": "^2.2.2",
        "vue-axios": "^2.0.1",
        "admin-lte": "^2.3.11"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "babel-core": "^6.1.2",
        "babel-loader": "^6.1.0",
        "babel-plugin-transform-runtime": "^6.1.2",
        "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.1.2",
        "babel-preset-stage-0": "^6.1.2",
        "babel-runtime": "^5.8.0",
        "webpack": "^1.12.2"
    },
    "author": "Me"
}
```

However, Install breaks and a UNC Path error occurs.

I think it has to do with CMD not being able to read network paths.

Full execution results:

[image: NPM Install Results]

Any workaround for this?

Comment: same problem here

Answer (score 2):

Solved this by using `pushd \\serverpath` in a cmd instance.

Then you will see something like : `Z:\>`.

Then restart git bash and do `cd Z:`

Everything works fine now

EDIT: Nope. Error is back so I am temporarly moving the files to a local drive for now. A fix would be highly appreciated!

Comment: Is it exactly the same error? You could use `net use Z: \\serverpath <password> /u:<username>` before `pushd` to ensure you access the share with a certain credential if you suspect it's an authentication issue.

Comment: Using git-bash the paths are different, for example you local C drive is `/c`, I think you should check the paths

Comment: I mapped the drive to a letter, opened a windows command prompt, changed to that drive and ran NPM install ..... and it seems to have worked.